# Excel Inbuilt Pivot Calculated Fields

Tags: excel, database, automation, pivot, formula

I would like to create an excel pivot table with inbuilt excel formulas please. I have a spreadsheet with Client A - D and the dates and items they have purchased.

[image]

I want to show the above in date ranges (<30 days ago, 30 - 60 days, 60 - 90 days, 90+ days).
So I complete my reporting as at Nov 30th 2023, I want to show within the last 30 days (etc.) the count of items purchased during that period.

I don't want to add additional formula columns to my data sheet, I want to ad calculated fields withing pivot table.

I have included a cell on my statistics spreadsheet where I can change the month end reporting date from Nov 30th to next reporting date as of Dec 31st.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use COUNTIFS but notice Pivot Tables do not allow to use functions in calculated field (or at least not all functions, just basic ones like ROUND and some more)

Comment: You can group dates/numbers in the pivot table (but not irregular groups) but you will have to calculate the difference from today in the source data. If you need your own groupings, you will have to add them somewhere - either in the raw source data, or in the data model if you are using that.